# Find each pair $(x,X)$ (a number and a matrix) that satisfy a condition.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to solve this problem, but I can't find an efficient way of doing so.

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two real, positive numbers, and $A$ and
>   $B$ two matrices: $$A = \pmatrix {0 & \alpha \\ \alpha & 0}, B = \pmatrix{0&\beta \\ \beta & 0}$$
>   Then, find each pair $(x,X)$ (where $x$ is a real number and $X$ is a
>   non-zero matrix) satisfying: $$AX+XB = xX$$

The only way I've been able to come up with implies writing $X$ explicitly, performing the multiplication on the left hand side of the equation, and then solving the $4 \times 4$ linear system to find explicit expressions for each element of $X$. I don't think this is the ideal way of solving it. Is there something I'm missing?

(Please note that this is not any type of homework, I just want to find a better solution for this, since I'm unable to solve the problem quickly.)

Comment: I've got as far as proving that $x=\pm (\alpha+\beta)$ OR $s+v=t+u=0$, if $X=\begin{pmatrix}s&t\\u&v\end{pmatrix}$. I don't think it will simplify the calculations much.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically leading to the same calculations as your solution, but we can regard this as an eigenvector problem.

Specifically, consider the linear map 
$$\varphi:\Bbb R^{2\times 2}\to \Bbb R^{2\times 2}, \ X\mapsto AX+XB$$
and write up its $4\times 4$ matrix $[\varphi]$ with respect to the standard basis of the (flattened) $2\times 2$ matrices.

Then calculate its eigenvalues by e.g. finding the roots of its characteristic polynomial, and then the corresponding eigenvectors.